# Div containing gallery won't center align horizontally

Tags: html, css, alignment

If you go to the following page: [play.yoozon.com](http://play.yoozon.com)

and do an inspect element on the gallery in the section titled "Screenshots", you should see the widths and margins I've used. For some reason, the group of screenshots seem to be shifted to the left, and I can't seem to center them without using padding, which adds extra space to the entire page and looks bad on mobile.

The reason why I haven't included code here is because I can't figure out which div is the relevant one for this problem, and a lot of it makes use of bootstrap, which would take up a ton of space here to include everything.

Answer (score 0):

your container: `.owl-wrapper` has a width of `1232px` while it's parent seems to be significantly smaller and set to `overflow: hidden`. Change `.owl-wrapper` to `width: 100%`. Then remove `float: left` from `.owl-item` and add `display: inline-block` instead. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your column with this..

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="width: 100%;">
<div id="owl-gallery" class="owl-carousel owl-theme" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">

    <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
        <div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 100%; left: 0px; display: block;">
            <div class="owl-item" style="width: 154px;">
                <div class="item"><a href="images/screenshot1@2x.png" data-lightbox-     
gallery="gallery1" data-lightbox-hidpi="images/screenshot1@2x.png">
                    <img src="images/screenshot1.png" class="img-responsive img-rounded"      
alt="img"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-item" style="width: 154px;">
                <div class="item"><a href="images/screenshot3@2x.jpg" data-lightbox-  
gallery="gallery1" data-lightbox-hidpi="images/screenshot3@2x.jpg">
                    <img src="images/screenshot3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded"  
alt="img"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-item" style="width: 154px;">
                <div class="item"><a href="images/screenshot2@2x.png" data-lightbox-
gallery="gallery1" data-lightbox-hidpi="images/screenshot2@2x.png">
                    <img src="images/screenshot2.png" class="img-responsive img-rounded"   


alt="img"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-item" style="width: 154px;">
                <div class="item"><a href="images/screenshot4@2x.jpg" data-lightbox-
gallery="gallery1" data-lightbox-hidpi="images/screenshot4@2x.jpg">
                    <img src="images/screenshot4.JPG" class="img-responsive img-rounded" 
alt="img"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="owl-controls clickable" style="display: none;">
        <div class="owl-pagination">
            <div class="owl-page"><span class=""></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with Bootstrap, but I know HTML & CSS.

I would set the width of your owl-wrapper div to 750px (this should be large enough to contain the 4 owl-item divs set to their current width of 182px). Then change the display to inline-block, the position to relative, and use margins to center like so:

```
<div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 750px; position: relative; margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block; -webkit-transition: all 0ms ease; transition: all 0ms ease;">
```

Also, if you want backwards compatibility with older versions of firefox, you may still wish to include the animation code with -moz prefix as well.

I hope that works for you! :)